# Read value of Concatenated Identifier or Path in JSX/React?

Tags: reactjs, variables, dynamic, concatenation, jsx

I tried all sorts of combination of syntax to try to read a dynamic path name, including concatenation techniques, with no success. Any clarity could be greatly appreciated!

**DYNAMIC PATH:** .question[**I**].state.DeltaTime**X**[**Y**]

with **I**, **X**, and **Y** all being dynamic integer values.

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
var I = 3
var X = 2
var Y = 1

var value= question[I].state.DeltaTimeX[Y];

//Im trying to read the value found at the following path: question[3].state.DeltaTime2[1],
//where a floating number exists at this location.
```

**IMAGE OF PATH IN DATABASE**

Yellow highlighted text is not dynamic.  Blue underlined is I, Red underlined is X, Black underlined is Y.

[image]

**ANSWER**
Thanks to Dave's comment below the solution to this problem would be to use code similiar to this:

```
question[I].state[`DeltaTime${X}`][Y]
```

Comment: You need to access the `DeltaTimeN` properties by constructing a string. Also note the typo in `DeltatTime3`.

Comment: How do i interject the value of a string variable into the path of an identifier? 

For example I ran the following : 
var x = 1;
var deltaNameInString = "DeltaTime1";
var realTest = question[i].state.deltaNameInString[x];

 however the value of deltaNameInString isn't actually read.

Comment: `question[I].state[\`DeltaTime${X}\`][Y]`

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH DAVE! IT WORKED :)

Comment: Glad you worked it out :)